# Can I use Euler's formula to prove a series converges to a rational value?

Tags: continued-fractions, mathematica, rationality-testing

Given the following infinite series with rational $x < 1$ && integer $n \geqslant 2$:

$$1-\frac{x}{n}+\frac{(1+n)x^2}{2n^2}-\frac{(1+n)(1+2n)x^3}{6n^3}+\frac{(1+n)(1+2n)(1+3n)x^4}{24n^4}-\ldots$$

Is it possible to prove certain values of $x, n$ will converge to a irrational result? I can generate an infinite generalized continued fraction with Euler's formula, but after transforming $a_i, b_i$ to positive integers $a_i>b_i$ which does not indicate whether the result is irrational or rational.

It seems that a regular continued fraction makes the determination trivial: Finite fractions are rational and infinite convergent fractions are irrational. Is there an algorithm/heuristic for converting to a regular continued fraction, or is that a manual process?

Comment: The series converges (if $|x|<1$) to $(1+x)^{-1/n}$.

Comment: As for the rest: yes, it is "manual". Regular continued fractions with *regular patterns* are rare.

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks for the answer! Curious how you found the closed form result. Is there a known technique for that part?

Comment: I just [recognized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) it.